Understanding Inconsistent Results in Pine Script
This Pine code give us strange results for example it gives us t = 0 , Result = 6552 , close = 6593,  so why ( t = close - Results ) give us 0 which is correct, but There is so difference between Results(6552) and close(6593) So we need the same outputs Result and close like if close 6593 than Result = 6593
//@version=5
indicator("Example code", overlay=true)

varip bool flag = true
var Result = 0.0
var t = 0.0

if flag
    Result := close
    t := (close - Result)
    flag := false
else
    na

plotshape(series=t, color=color.yellow, title='t')
plotshape(series=Result, color=color.red, title='Result')
plot(series=close, color=color.lime, title='close')


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
